# Sync deleted user in GitLab

Tags: azure-active-directory, gitlab

Our GitLab server is connected with our Azure AD and we sync the users every day.

I accidentally deleted a user from GitLab  (not from our AD) and now it is not re importing that user. Is there any way to restore the user or force a sync on that person?

Comment: Have you tried to de-register the user from Gitapp application on AD and then re-registering it?

Comment: What is Gitapp? I don't think we are using it.

Comment: I meant to say "git" application which is registered on Azure AD for provisioning users from Azure to GitLab.

Answer (score 0):

Thank [Srinath Menon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4444577/srinath-menon) for giving a comment. I am converting it as an answer to help other community member.

Git lab server is integrated with git application in azure enterprise application. Deleting a user from git lab server might not sync deleted from git application so you need to deregister it from git application for importing the same user in git lab server.

Note: “git” application which is registered on Azure AD for provisioning users from Azure to GitLab.